# Adding filter to inline raw_id_field in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I have a data model as below:

```
    
    class School(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField()

    class Candidate(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField()
        school = models.ForeignKey(School)

    class Skill(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField()
        school = models.ForeignKey(School)

    class CandidateSkill(models.Model):
        candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate)
        skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, related_name='candidate_skills')
```

And in the admin I have:

```
    class CandidateSkillInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = CandidateSkill
        form = CandidateSkillInlineForm
        fields = ('skill', )
        raw_id_fields = ('skill',)

    class CandidateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        model = Candidate
        fields = ('name', 'school')
        inlines = [CandidateSkillInline]
```

What I am trying to achieve is when I click the skill raw_id_field from the CandidateAdmin I want to list only the skills that belong to the school of the candidate. How can I achieve this?